# content of HEAD file inside .git folder is different

Tags: git

I just started playing with git.

Initialized git in two different folders called GitT1 and GitT2. Added simple file and played around. And now I see that content of the HEAD(inside the .git folder) show different for the two. 
GitT1 shows

**ref: refs/heads/master**

and GitT2 shows the commit id(SHA-1)

**0a54a52982ac1340fdcac44cc5f874e9ce85a110**

I understand both of them, one is SHA-1(commit ID) and the other points to the branch. So the question is why are these two different?

**EDIT**

One thing is I did checkout to move the HEAD on GitT2 so if I do git status, it says

**HEAD detached from 7448b1a**

**nothing to commit, working tree clean**

Is this anything to do with the HEAD?

Comment: Run `cat .git/refs/heads/master` to see what it is. `HEAD` is a ref. `refs/heads/master` is a ref too. A ref can point to a sha1 as well as to another ref.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But under what circumstance does it do that. I begin to feel that since I detached that head, It is showing the sha directly. Any way may not be that important.

Comment: `HEAD` always points to the current checked-out revision. If the revision is a branch (`git checkout master`), HEAD refers to the branch. Id the revision is a commit (`git checkout 7448b1a`), HEAD refers to the commit. A detached head is a nameless branch.